# Magento2 - Livechat Node.js and Socket.io

Tags: magento2, extensions

I need to develop new live chat application using socket.io and Node.js for reference http://socket.io/get-started/chat/. Magneto2 can support Node.js and Socket.io.

Comment: @Amit Bera  if you know suggest  me

Comment: @ Alan Kent  if you know suggest me

Comment: Yes, you can see Chat System for Magento 2 of WebKul. They have implemented socket for their livechat extension